# função de exclusão em LISP

Tags: lisp

Estou com dúvidas em como fazer uma outra função para exclusão do nome e do telefone.

Segue o código que fiz:

```
(defun incluir (Agenda  NomeTelefone)
    (cond ((atom A) (cons NT 'nil))
          ((equal (car NT) (caar A))
              (cond ((existeFone (cadr NT) (cdar A))A)
                    ('t (cons(cons(car NT)(cons (cadr NT)(cdar A))) (cdr A)))))
          ('t (cons(car A)(incluir (cdr A) NT)))))

//função existeFone 
(defun existeFone (NT A)
    (cond ((equal NT A) A)
          ('t (cons (cons(car NT)(cons (cadr NT)(cdar A))) (cdr A))))
```

Comment: Sugestão: sempre indente seu código Lisp, senão você vai ficar doido de tanto contar parênteses... :P

Comment: P.S. Tem vários parênteses faltando na função `existeFone`, não? (antes de `NT`, antes de `(equal` e um fechando no final).

Comment: sim, estava faltando ,fui corrigir e acabei esquecendo de arrumar, obrigado por corrigir!!

Comment: Eu não tinha corrigido (em geral, só o autor da pergunta deve mexer no seu código, exceto pela indentação), mas com sua confirmação, fiz isso agora. :)

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? Qual é o formato da entrada? Qual erro você está tendo?

Comment: não estou conseguindo fazer a função de excluir.

Comment: Você quer excluir pelo nome, pelo telefone ou por ambos? Digo, se uma outra pessoa com aquele telefone (mas nome diferente) estiver na agenda, a função deve fazer o quê? Se a pessoa tiver mais de um telefone (você parece tratar esse caso), a função deve apagar todos ou só o que foi especificado?

Answer (score 0):

Para "excluir" um telefone da lista, podemos montar uma nova lista recursivamente com todos os valores que não sejam o que queremos.

```
(defun excluir (valor lista)
  (cond
     ((eql nil lista) nil) ;lista vazia/fim da lista, retornamos nada
     ((and ;verificamos se os dois campos são iguais
          (equalp (car valor) (caar lista)) ;comparamos primeiro campo
          (equalp (cadr valor) (cadar lista))) ;comparamos o segundo
           (excluir valor (cdr lista))) ;pulamos ele e pegamos o resto,
      (t (cons (car lista) (excluir valor (cdr lista)))))) ;não é o valor, adicionamos ele ao resto da lista montada recursivamente
```